# Grails CXF plugin and GORM

Tags: hibernate, grails

I'm using the CXF plugin version 2.0.1 and have a simple usage of GORM in a SOAP service method. When I run a test on the service, it throws an exception saying that it could not initialize a proxy because there was no session. According to some searches I did, this is a Hibernate issue which I am assuming means that GORM has not been properly initialized. Could someone give me a pointer on how to initialize GORM manually within the endpoint class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're used to doing Hibernate work in controller actions (or methods called from there) and there's always an active Hibernate Session there because Grails uses the Open Session in View pattern, opening a session at the beginning of the request, binding it in a ThreadLocal so it can be conveniently accessed, and then flushing and closing the session at the end of the request. Some plugins do this also, for example the Quartz plugin uses job start/stop listeners to do the same thing so you can conveniently use GORM there just like in a controller.

The easiest way to ensure that a session is open for the duration of block of code is to use the static `withTransaction` method on any domain class. It does start a transaction, so if you do database updates you'll also benefit from that, but even if you're only reading it is the way to go because the session will be open, and you'll be able to work with lazy-loaded 1-many and many-many references.

The transaction/session have nothing to do with the domain class, so pick a random one and use it:

```
User.withTransaction {

   def games = Game.findAllByFooAndBar(foo, bar)
   games.each { ... }
   ...
}
```